# itinerar todos los elementos de un array contra todos los elementos de otro array

Tags: python, math

Teniendo dos numpy.ndarray como el siguiente

```
Out[1662]: 
array([[ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1],
       ...,
```

y otro de estructura idéntica llamemoslo B

me gustaría saber cómo con un bucle for puedo coger el primer elemento de A (00) y enfrentarlo a todos y cada uno de B, cuando esto acabe coger el segundo elemento de A (01) y enfrentarlo con todos y cada uno de B.

Para mas info, pongo aquí mi código completo

```
import numpy as np

def inSphere( point, ref, radius):

    # Calculate the difference between the reference and measuring point
    diff = np.subtract(point, ref)

    # Calculate square length of vector (distance between ref and point)^2
    dist = np.sum(np.power(diff, 2))

    # If dist is less than radius^2, return True, else return False
    return dist < radius ** 2
```

Hasta aqui, este codigo compara una fila del array a por ejemplo a[1]  con otra fila del array b[2].

Lo cual es lo que yo quiero pero ahora lo quiero itinerar para que esa operacion me la haga el 1 del a con todos los del B, el dos del A con todos los del B, ... Y me devuelva en cada True un 1 y lo vaya sumando al objeto numero.

Esto es lo que he intentado

```
numero = 0
for i in range (len(puntos1)):
    if inSphere( puntos1[i], puntos2[j], 4) == True:
        numero +=1
```

Se que debe de ser facil pero soy nuevo y no logro hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema se resuelve anidando un for dentro del que ya tienes. De hecho usas una variable j que no declaras y pudieras declararla en ese for anidado. Algo como esto:

```
numero = 0
for i in range (len(puntos1)):
    for j in range(len(puntos2)):
        if inSphere( puntos1[i], puntos2[j], 4):
            numero +=1
```

Fijate que en la sentencia if he eliminado el == True pues es algo un poco redundante y poco pythonico. Si esto no responde tu problema no temas en decirlo y comentar un poco mejor lo que realmente quieres.

Comment: Hola Alejandro,
Gracias por tu ayuda. Si no entiendo mal, el codigo que me propones lo que hace es coger el primer elemento de puntos1 y "enfrentarlo" con todos los elementos de puntos2, desde el primero hasta el ultimo, cuando esto acaba, vuelve al segundo elemento de puntos1 y lo enfrenta con todos los elementos desde el primero hasta el ultimo de los elementos de puntos2 y asi hasta el ultimo elemento de puntos1 verdad? 

Corrigeme si me equivoco por favor

Comment: Exactamente, los ciclos anidados se pueden usar de esa manera y pueden tener la profundidad que desees. Para cada etapa del ciclo que itera sobre la variable i, se realiza un ciclo completo sobre la variable j. Esta combinacion es muy util en programacion y se puede utilizar en cualquier lenguaje.

Comment: Si entiendo tu codigo, cada fila de esos arreglos que utilizas es un punto en el espacio cartesiano y el primer arreglo es una lista de puntos. El segundo arreglo es una lista de otros puntos de referencia. Lo que quieres es determinar cuantos puntos de la primera lista estan contenidos dentro de las esferas de radio "radius" y con centros en los puntos de la segunda lista. De todos modos te dare otra respuesta para aclarar esa logica

Answer (score 0):

Mira esta variante:

```
import numpy as np

puntos = np.array([[1,1,1],
                   [2,2,2],
                   [3,2,1],
                   [9,3,6]])

# Llamemos centro de referencia A al punto [2,3,4]
# y centro de referencia B al punto [4,1,5]
centros = np.array([[2,3,4],
                    [4,1,5]])

def inSphere( point, ref, radius):
    # Calculate the difference between the reference and measuring point
    diff = np.subtract(point, ref)
    # Calculate square length of vector (distance between ref and point)^2
    dist = np.sum(np.power(diff, 2))
    # If dist is less than radius^2, return True, else return False
    return dist < radius ** 2
# Puntos de la lista dentro de la esfera con centro en A y radio 5
numeroA = 0
# Puntos de la lista dentro de la esfera con centro en B y radio 5
numeroB = 0

for i in range (len(puntos)):
    for j in range(len(centros)):
        if inSphere(puntos[i], centros[j], 5):
            if j == 0:
                numeroA += 1
            elif j == 1:
                numeroB += 1

print("Hay {} puntos de la lista 'puntos' que se encuentran dentro de la esfera con centro en [2,3,4] y radio 5".format(numeroA))
print("Hay {} puntos de la lista 'puntos' que se encuentran dentro de la esfera con centro en [4,1,5] y radio 5".format(numeroB))
```

LO que hacia el codigo anterior era calcular la suma total de las veces que cada punto se habia encontrado dentro de cada una de las esferas. En este ejemplo que te pongo, donde numeroA = 3 y numeroB = 2, ese total seria 5. Pero bueno, ya eso depende de que es lo que realmente necesitas. Espero haberte ayudado en algo.